# Zend Framework url setting for Https

Tags: zend-framework, url, https

I have Zend Framework application and i use SSL certificate in login and signup page. I don't need "https" login and signup page other than all url. But url helper set "https" to all url at signup or login page.

How to disable "https" for others url?

Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You should realize that the same site on http:// and https:// are 2 different sites for the browser. So when logging in all protected pages need to get accessed through the https links.

Besides that the url view helper doesn't prepend the site url but only the path for the current URL.
So if you want to switch to http you'd need to redirect in your controllers/bootstrap or manually add the full url with http to the links which need to direct a user to the http protocol again.